# Determining that a string is a valid HTML element

Tags: php, html

I'm having trouble getting this constraint `matches` function to match all HTML elements.

It must return true for any legitimate, properly-formed HTML element and return false for anything that is not a legitimate, properly-formed HTML element.

The following are things that did *not* work:

- `$dom = new \DOMDocument(); return $dom->loadHTML($value);`
- `$dom = new \DOMDocument(); return $dom->loadHTML($value,LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);`
- Adding the flag `LIBXML_NOENT` to `simplexml_load_string()`.
- Adding the flag `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` to `simplexml_load_string()`.

Here is the current function:

```
function matches($value)
{
    \libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    if (!\is_string($value) || empty($value)) {
        return false;
    }

    $start = \strpos($value, '<');
    $end = \strrpos($value, '>', $start);

    $len = \strlen($value);

    if ($end !== false) {
        $value = \substr($value, $start);
    } else {
        $value = \substr($value, $start, $len - $start);
    }
    $value = \html_entity_decode($value);
    $value = \str_replace('&', '', $value);

    \libxml_clear_errors();
    $xml = \simplexml_load_string($value);
    return \count(\libxml_get_errors()) === 0;
}
```

The current version has two known problems:

- `<script>&</script>`: Should fail but passes.
- `<a b="&quot;"></a>`: Should pass but fails.

Comment: How about self closing tags?

Comment: Why `<script>&</script>` should fail? As far as the HTML parser is concerned this is valid HTML. In fact there isn't a lot that isn't valid HTML. HTML is by design very flexible and forgiving and the browser will present the best it can whatever mess you present it with, there is no such thing as a HTML error.

Comment: OK, I can take that case out. That leaves the other case which should pass.